# Writing output in a function of a class is what I should not do?

Tags: php, psr-1

Lately I'm trying to adapt to the PSR standard. On the [PSR-1 document](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) it is stated that:

> Files SHOULD either declare symbols (classes, functions, constants,
>   etc.) or cause side-effects (e.g. generate output, change .ini
>   settings, etc.) but SHOULD NOT do both.

Does this mean that writing output (lets say `echo '<b>some bold text</b>';`) in a function which is in a class is what I should not do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not what that means.

All it refers to is what happens when you `include` those files. The result of `include 'foo.php'` should *either* be a bunch of new symbols (classes, functions, constants) having been created, *or* some side effect to have happened (autoloader was added, HTML output was generated, or generally something *happened*). These two things should not be mixed, since you often want to load classes without also causing some inevitable side effect.

If you 1) `include` the file and then 2) explicitly call a function which produces a side effect, that's perfectly fine. Otherwise all code which produces side effects could not be written in classes or functions, which is simply nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up with examples.

#### Bad example (mixed)

```
<?php

namespace Foo;

class Bar
{
  // ...
}

?>
<b>some text here</b>
```

#### Good example #1 (class declaration)

```
<?php

namespace Foo;

class Bar
{
  // ...
}
```

#### Good example #2 (template)

```
<b>some text here</b>
<?php echo "hello world"; ?>
```

Comment: Well, yeah, this part is clear to me, but will the 'good example #1' still be good, if in the class there would be a method which writes output?

Comment: @VitaliusKuchalskis I'm surprised it's still mentioned as a recommendation rather than hard rule ;-)